# Game network code - Client side prediction & correction

Tags: c++, networking, winsock

I'm creating a 2d sidescroller mmorpg using winsock and c++ and I wanted to ask how to program client-side prediction & correction?
Well especially the correction, because prediction is basically just running the physics code you have running on the server on the client.
The server sends corrections about every two seconds. This messages contains X & Y positions and X & Y velocity and the Input like
left 0, right 1, jump 1...

Edit:
Is it ok that I do the same for other clients? So instead of sending snapshots of position and velocity, I only send input that has changed, and the local
client will predict where the other clients are moving to. The server sends corrections every 2-3 seconds.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 7):

Typically what is done in games of this type:

1. Prediction is "dead-reckoning" where server has the client moving with some constant velocity (of course adjusting this velocity for gravity, explosions, and whatever else occurs on the server) until the client updates its current position and velocity. For an action game it is hard to come up with any more advanced prediction than this velocity*time movement (i.e. trying to predict what input is coming).
2. Telling the server where you are is a tricky matter. If the server relies on players to send their own positions and velocities, a client can spoof his/her position to get around obstacles. Ideally the server would just receive client input and process the resulting movement directly, so it can be certain that people are moving around in a legitimate manner. However the delay in getting the input to the server makes this impractical, so you may need a middle ground solution where the client says "I was right here at (x,y) when I changed my velocity to (s,t)" (i.e. the jump key was pressed at point x,y) and the server looks at this information and says "according to my predictive motion for this client, he actually was fairly near that point just 0.7 seconds ago, so I believe that he really did change his velocity to (s,t) at that point. And my prediction for the last 0.7 second was inaccurate, so the player is actually at (x,y) + (s,t)*0.7" If the server disagrees, it should tell the player where it thinks her or she is currently at so that the player snaps back to the position the server indicates. For example if an explosion occurred on the server before the client's input got to the server, then the client's view of himself in the world is no longer accurate. Likewise if the client is trying to send a false position far from his current location or an absurdly high movement velocity. The server has to lay the smack down, so to speak :)
3. The server sends to each client the position and velocity of each player *in his or her vicinity*. The position and velocity are enough to fully predict and extrapolate player movement. In other words, the other players don't care which keys are being pressed or anything like that, the confirmation of accuracy was already made by the server. NPC movements and AI can be processed on the client side, so they don't need to be sent.
4. Networked games are almost *always* done with UDP sockets. UDP sockets have much lower overhead than TCP because packets are not acknowledged by the recipient. If they are lost, they are gone for good. While this saves an acknowledgement round trip, you can't assume that a packet ever got to the server or vice versa. This is the tricky thing about sending input events. It is ideal to always send current state "snapshots" rather than changes in state, because even if packets are lost in transit, you know the correct state as soon as a packet does come in. In other words, you always want to say "this is where I am and what I'm currently doing" rather than, "I pressed Jump 3 times".

So to summarize, clients could send velocity updates and the position where the avatar was when the change occurred. The server verifies all current states for reasonable values. The server sends this data to other nearby players (ideally packing all the motion info for nearby players into a single packet), and the clients apply the same prediction model minus the verification of reasonable motion.

Sorry if this is too long...